# Javascript older than 18 on leap years

Tags: javascript, leap-year

I'm using this javascript to check if the age entered is older than 18.

```
        function calculateDiffYear(date, month, year)
        {
            var cur = new Date();
            var diff = Math.floor((cur.getTime() - new Date(year, month, date)) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000));
                diff -= Math.floor((cur.getFullYear() - year) / 4);

            return diff / 365;
        }

        function checkBorn(sender)
        {
            var root = sender.form;
            var date = root.elements['date'].value;
            var month = root.elements['month'].value - 1;
            var year = root.elements['year'].value;

            if (!isValidDate(date, month, year) || calculateDiffYear(date, month, year) < 18) return false;

            return true;
        }
```

If works almost right, except for, if we are in a leap year, it gives older than 18 to a person who becomes 18 **tomorrow**, at least in the tests I'm doing with today date and changing to las year. I tryed adding this but no luck:

```
if ($('#leap').val()) divider = 366;
else divider = 365;

return diff / divider;
```

Do you know how can I solve it?

Thank you

Comment: A year is actually 365.25 days which is why we need leap years in the first place.   Does using 365.25 in place of 365 fix your math?

Comment: @Sparky672: Actually a year is 365.24 days. That's why every 400 years we *don't* have a leap year.

Comment: Dividing by 365.24 (or .25) fails, as it gives less than 18 for someone becoming 18 today or even 2 days ago, I'll try @nnnnnn solution now...

Comment: @Kolink,  I'll keep that in mind next time I'm writing code that needs to run for several hundred years.  (and it's actually 365.242199 for any application that requires such accuracy)

Comment: @Kolink - every 400 years we _do_ have a leap year. It is every _100_ years that we don't, _unless_ the year is also divisible by 400.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant - I couldn't remember off the top of my head XD

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I wanted to test if a particular date was more than 18 years ago I'd do something like this:

```
function meetsMinimumAge(birthDate, minAge) {
    var tempDate = new Date(birthDate.getFullYear() + minAge, birthDate.getMonth(), birthDate.getDate());
    return (tempDate <= new Date());
}

if (meetsMinimumAge(new Date(year, month, date), 18)) {
    // is OK, do something
} else {
    // too young - error
}
```

Essentially this takes the supplied birthday, adds 18 to it, and checks if that is still on or before today's date.

Comment: ok if your checking the year, month and date arguments first (if the arguments are NULL, a minimal date will be created)!

Comment: @silly - as written, my `meetsMinimumAge()` function simply accepts a date and a minimum age to test against, it doesn't construct a date from individual date parts, so it is assumed that whatever calls that function will supply a valid date (otherwise garbage-in-garbage-out applies). This doesn't slot directly into the OP's existing code, but the main point is it shows an easy way to test for an age of x years - adapting the parameters or whatever is trivial.

Comment: So simple! It's easy to fall into the trap of subtracting birthdate from now and trying to deal with the leap years when all we really need to do is look at the problem more naturally and ask "is the eighteenth birthday before or after now?"

Answer (score 1):

My age-checking code goes something like this:

```
function checkAge(dateofbirth) {
    var yd, md, dd, now = new Date();
    yd = now.getUTCFullYear()-dateofbirth.getUTCFullYear();
    md = now.getUTCMonth()-dateofbirth.getUTCMonth();
    dd = now.getUTCDate()-dateofbirth.getUTCDate();
    if( yd > 18) return true;
    if( md > 0) return true;
    return dd >= 0;
}
```

Basically, if the year difference is 19 or more, then they must be over 18.

Otherwise, if the current month is past the month of birth, they are 18 and a few months old.

Otherwise, if the current day is greater than or equal to the day of birth, they are 18 and a few days old (or it is their 18th birthday).

This works regardless of leap years and is much more efficient than your current code.

Comment: thanks its usefull but it took me some time to convert my string 01/02/1999 for example to date with method `getUTCFullYear()` it took only `getFullYear()` because its not supported or something in this particualr situation

Comment: i called it like this `checkAge(new Date(InfoDateOfBirth.value.split("/")[2],
            InfoDateOfBirth.value.split("/")[1],
            InfoDateOfBirth.value.split("/")[0]))` and worked other wise if passed as string there is shortage in age by 2 year s app i dont know why and it worked for `getUTCFullYear()` regarding my last comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to validate it:

```
var yourDate = year.toString() + "/" + month.toString() + "/" day.toString();

var date = moment(yourDate, "YYYY/MM/DD"); // There are other formats!
var years = moment().diff(date, 'years', false);

if(years >= 18){
    return true;
}

return false;
```